# Matlab title() in loglog plot not working under some conditions

Tags: matlab

I'm having a problem getting the title to set for some loglog plots in Matlab.  The title function works fine when plotting the same data using plot(x,y), but fails to display when using loglog(x,y).  I thought it might be a bug triggered by the data, but it looks like I was wrong - please see the commenting below.

```
%title_prob
figure
x=0:1:1000;                     
y=3*x.^x;                       %The sum of this vecor is Inf
loglog(x,y)
title('Title','FontSize',16)    %This title doesn't set
xlabel('X Label','FontSize',12)
ylabel('Y Label','FontSize',12)

figure
x2=0:1:100;
y2=3*x2.^x2;                    %The sum of this vector is finite
loglog(x2,y2)
title('Title','FontSize',16)    %This title does set
xlabel('X Label','FontSize',12)
ylabel('Y Label','FontSize',12)

%Further investigation - is Inf to blame?  Apparently not.
FirstInf=max(find(y<Inf))+1;
figure
loglog(x(1:FirstInf),y(1:FirstInf))
title('Inf value in the y vector','FontSize',16)    %Title not set

figure
loglog(x(1:FirstInf-1),y(1:FirstInf-1))
title('NO Inf value in the y vector','FontSize',16) %Title not set
figure
plot(x,y)
title('Works for the plot function','FontSize',16)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title position is always calculated in axes coordinates based on upper `y` limit. So if it's `Inf` the title position will be also Inf and it will not be visible.

When you are taking out the Inf value from `y` (figure 4), the next value is still very large, about 1e306. To calculate title's position MATLAB adds some number to upper y limit (little below 1.8e308, check by `ylim`) and it becomes Inf (1.8e308 is already Inf). Check double values limit with REALMAX.

You can check the title position with

```
get(get(gca,'title'),'position')
```

So, yes, it is Inf values that make your title disappear.

You can set the y axis limit manually before calling `title`:

```
yl = ylim;
ylim([yl(1), 10^302])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I now realise that title('') is just the same as text(x,y,'') where x and y are set by the title function.  Good to know!  It didn't occur to me to search for the title using get - I just assumed something bad had happened...  Thanks.

Comment: @ZetaSeeker: Technically, title set not by `title` function, but at axes generation. It's the property of any axes. `title` function is just an easy way to **change** title and its properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
%Further investigation - is Inf to blame?  Apparently not.
FirstInf=max(find(y<Inf))+1;
figure
loglog(x(1:FirstInf),y(1:FirstInf))
title('Inf value in the y vector','FontSize',16)    %Title not set
```

Yes but you may have a NAN right there in the first position, in **y(1)**. As 0^0 is undefined, so perhaps that is causing the anomaly.

Edit. Technically 0^0 is undefined because the limit depends upon which way you approach zero in the augmements. Lim x^0 (as x goes to zero from above) is **1**, whereas lim 0^x (as x goes to zero) is **0**. That's why it's technically undefined.

However I just checked in gnu-Octave and 0^0 returned 1 without any issues. So probably Matlab returns the same. So I guess this isn't the answer, but I'll leave it here anyway as someone might be interested in the technical difficulties with 0^0.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; On my system 0/0=NaN, but 0^0=1 so this isn't what is causing the problem.

Comment: Out of interest, if you paste the above code into Octave does it plot the titles for all the figures?

Comment: Yep I just tested it. It looks like much the same problem. In my case Octave didn't plot anything, or even draw the axes, if I plotted past "FirstInf". The index of the first non-inf term was 143, but surprisingly loglog(x(1:143),y(1:143)) also failed. It looks like there must be some internal overflow in loglog at a slightly lower max value than the raw data would suggest. For me, plotting to max indexes of 142 and 141 also failed, but loglog(x(1:140),y(1:140)) and below plotted aok.

Comment: BTW. There is also an issue in loglog with the first x value, x(1) being zero, but it handles this gracefully. Not that it's a problem, but if you want to avoid it there's always semilogy(). FWIW semilogy() gave the same issue in terms of the maximum index I could plot up to, again being y(140).

Comment: After you posted your comments I began searching for the exact limits of y data that would cause the title function to crash, but then yuk posted above.  Thanks for your help Stuart, appreciated.